# Why is QGIS reading in my CSV numeric data as string data, and how do I change it?

Tags: qgis, data, convert, csv

QGIS keeps reading in my numeric data from .csv files as string data. This means I have to  figure out how to read it in with the proper data type, or convert it back to numeric inside of QGIS, neither of which I know how to do. Why is it doing this, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at @underdark's tutorial on [How to Specify Data Types of CSV Columns for Use in QGIS](http://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest creating a schema.ini file for your CSV data. If it doesn't exist, create an empty file and call it schema.ini. Edit it following the instructions found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As an example, if your csv is called output1.csv, and the second column is called myValues and you want to make sure it is read as a long integer, the following would take care of it. You'll need to restart QGIS after creating the schema.ini.

```
[output1.csv]
Col2=myValues Long
```

Comment: Are you sure that works? ogr uses a csvt file format.